# python syntax error using lambda function inside rename method

Tags: python

I am trying to use below code locally with python version 3.7.4 and it works fine

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(df[c].astype(str).str.split(',').tolist())
                   .rename(lambda x: f'Field{x + 1}', axis=1) for c in df.columns]      
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
```

I tried to run the same script in jenkins and it fails with below error.

- python3 test.py

  ```
  File "test.py", line 33
    .rename(lambda x: f'Field{x + 1}', axis=1) for c in df.columns]
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

Is it related to python version? I use pip3 install boto3 to install aws python package to run python script.

Comment: what is `f'Field{x+1}'` supposed to do?

Comment: did that but doesn't work